# Reference (and Copy) Part of Table Header Row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stumped, but I feel like the answer is going to be easy.

Ultimately, I want a list validation drop down from a table header row that doesn't include the first two columns and in reverse order. The reason is because the table has dates going from least recent to most recent, left to right, but I want the drop down to have the most recent date at the top, not at the bottom. The best way I've found to do that so far is to create an array above the header row that is in the reverse order of the header row, then have the drop down refer to that one instead. If you can think of a better way, by all means, please let me know!

This would be easier if I didn't need a table with a header, but I'm 99% that's a must. I've considered just using a formula, but I need it to automatically extend with the header row as more columns are added. Therefore, VBA seems like my best bet.

Here is the code I've cobbled together so far. It's not too complicated, just iterates through each cell in the header row, adds it to Arr(Cl), then spits it out on the row above and gives it a defined name.

```
Public Sub FlipSelection()

Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim Rng As Range 'or ListObject?
Dim C As Range
Dim Cl As Long

Set Rng = Sheet33.ListObjects(1)
Sheets33.Range(Rng.ListColumns("C3").Range.Cells(1, 1), Rng.ListColumns("F3")._
Range.Cells(1, 1)).Address 'this is where I'm having the issue
'Set Rng = Sheet33.Range.[C3], [3:3].Find("*", [C3], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)_
'this works for a row in a table, but not the header row for some reason
Cl = Rng.Columns.Count
ReDim Arr(Cl)

Cl = 0
For Each C In Rng
    Arr(Cl) = C.Formula
    Cl = Cl + 1
Next C

Cl = Cl - 1
For Each C In Rng.Offset(-1, 0)
    C.Formula = Arr(Cl)
    Cl = Cl - 1
    'Sheet33.Names.Add Name:="Test2", RefersTo:=Sheet33.Range([C2], [2:2].Find("*",_
'[A2], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)) 'same as above, works fine with a table row, but not_
'the header row
Next C

End Sub
```

[image: I do not want the first two columns to be flipped and copied above, so it should look like this.]

Comment: Note that you should probably be referring to `Rng.HeaderRowRange` - that is the header row. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.headerrowrange) for more detail.

Comment: Can't you use a formual in data-validation for the dropdown? i.e. if your table is called Table1:
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Table1[#Headers]"),0,COLUMNS(INDIRECT("Table1[#Headers]"))-3,1,3)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that @BigBen, but I can't figure out a way to exclude the first two columns if I do that.

Comment: @userMT I tried that too but can't get it to reverse the order of the header, otherwise that would be the simplest answer I think.